# module.exports all the functions within a js file

Tags: javascript, node.js, syntax

I would like to export all the functions within a JS file without specifying individually in `module.exports` which ones to export

Example

```
function test1() {
  // do something
}
function test2() {
  // do something
}
function test3() {
  // do something
}

module.exports = {
  test1,
  test2,
  test3
}
```

Comment: Don't think it's possible - which is *good*, exports should be explicit

Comment: As it's written this works fine, but yes you need to explicitly export methods, classes, etc.

Answer (score 2):

There is no way to automatically export all functions in a file because there is no way to enumerate all functions within the module scope.   Javascript does not provide a way to iterate all variables or functions declared within a function scope.

Instead, you could declare all your functions as properties on some object and then either enumerate all the properties on that object and assign them to exports or just directly export that object.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of a way to automagically have all the functions in a file exported, but if you're just looking for a way to remove boilerplate, you could define them directly under the exports:

```
module.exports = {
    test1: function test1() { /* code */ },
    test2: function test2() { /* code */ },
    test3: function test3() { /* code */ }
}
```